# Architecture to Save word documents with search options

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

We are building an internal application where users have the option to save word documents in the system,But the issue is the users should have the ability to search for these documents by keywords.
We use asp.net,c# and Sqlserver 2008.I was wondering to save these documents in a Varchar field and then searching these fields for keywords or do i need to use full text search using Solr/Lucene.

I would like to know if this is the efficient design for this purpose.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Ad: consider using SharePoint as it already provides indexing of Word documents. Local Windows search indexes Word documents too.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov thats a really good suggestion, you could just use WSS and not have to purchase the full blown SPS: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=14117

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have to store word documents in the database and you wish to be able to search them by some classic keywords then use a [Virtual Path Provider](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/910441), each time the document is saved put some keywords in a dB field and search using those keywords. This method will get around the DB Copy that John3136 mentioned.

If you need to be able to search on the content of the documents you wont be able to do that if the files are saved as blobs, so for this purpose it may make more sense to save the documents as XML Word 2003 and configure a Full Text search to ignore angle brackets, eg:

```
Regex.Replace(dBFieldOfWordXMLData, @"<[^>]*>", string.Empty);
```

I think the most efficient way is to use a Virtual Path Provider, MSDN Articles and Sharepoint documents use Virtual Path Provider and they are searchable. I've done some research on what the most efficient solution would be  came across EpiServer CMS on Azure: http://episerverazurevpp.codeplex.com/

Comment: So are you saying dont even bother to save it to a database? just save it as XML word 2003 files ?

Comment: both options I say DO save to the dB. The 1st approach is storing the word documents into a blob field via Virtual Path Provider. The 2nd approach is saying if you need to search document content you're not going to be do it when the file is saved into a blob field - so I was saying that you could save the Document as XML into a varchar(MAX) field and you could get a Full-Text search on the varchar field if it ignored XML tags. The final recommendation is saying use a VPP but then look into Full Text search options that work with VPP. I'll do a bit more research, see what MS did to overcome it

Comment: With the 2nd approach, Does it have to be stored in the database as XML ? Or can it be stored as just plain text ?And then use Full text search against that field ?

Answer (score 0):

Without more details this is impossible to answer sensibly. A few things to consider:

Are you saying save the whole doc into a varchar field in a DB? That doesn't really sound smart - you have the whole problem of keeping the DB copy in sync with the disc copy (not to mention the whole idea of a DB copy in the first place...)

You mention keywords: If there are a limited number of keywords then it is fairly easy to write an office interop app that searches a word doc for keywords. You could either do this on save and keep a DB of which docs contain which words, or you could do it "on the fly" (i.e. an app that searches a whole folder full of docs for the ones containing a particular word) - it all depends on how many docs you are likely to have, required performance etc.

Could you do something with the document properties (add your own custom property corresponding to a keyword) and search for files with that property?

Comment: Once i save the document, i dont need to keep the disc copy.So i can even save it to a blob field.But not sure if that will help me search on the field. On retrival i wont be showing the disc copy, but just show the whole text on a memo field.

Comment: So you don't really need a word doc then - just the text that was in the word doc? - that is a pretty big change. Makes the DB idea more feasible...